# How do I override a field handler?

Tags: 7, views, theming

Using Drupal 7, I have a block that displays a view. It contains a simple aggregator list view. The aggregator item titles are links to an external website and I want them to open in a new window.

I found the code that renders the link in `modules/aggregator/views_handler_field_aggregator_title_link.inc, line 45` in class `views_handler_field_aggregator_title_link` function `render_link()`
https://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules%21aggregator%21views_handler_field_aggregator_title_link.inc/function/views_handler_field_aggregator_title_link%3A%3Arender_link/7.x-3.x

I can add `$this->options['alter']['target'] = '_blank';` to make the link render correctly, but obviously I don't want to change the core module code. What is the correct place to achieve this?

Comment: It would be in one of the [Views hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7.x-3.x), possibly in [`hook_views_pre_render`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7.x-3.x) you'll be able to do the same thing as you did to hack the Views code. But not knowing what type of view/display you have there it's hard to say, most of the time you can just control this setting on the View admin UI by checking "Open link in new window" or something

Comment: To be more specific about the view type: I have a View containing a Block that contains type Aggregator Item. It renders an Unformatted List. I am configuring the title field. Unfortunately it only has the relevant option "Display as link".

Comment: Looking at the hooks list, `pre_render` seems like the correct one. Could you point me in the right direction as to where to implement this hook? I am guessing most appropiate would be in a template file.

Comment: I found a way to accomplish this using the Drupal interface, but I'm still interested to learn how to do this using a custom field handler or hook. :)